# MySQL FULLTEXT match with distinct results

Tags: mysql, database

I'm wanting to run a FULLTEXT search and return only results with a distinct (unique) product_name, but the `DISTINCT(product_name)` doesn't seem to be applying. Any help or pointers in the right direction would be greatly received.

**MySQL QUERY:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT(product_name), sku
FROM products
WHERE MATCH(product_name)
AGAINST('Flixonase' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
LIMIT 5
```

**Current result:**

```
product_name                     sku
FLIXONASE NASAL 24 HR SPRAY 60D  9300673808851
FLIXONASE NASAL 24 HR SPRAY 120D 9400600822438
FLIXONASE NASAL 24 HR SPRAY 60D  930067308851
FLIXONASE NASAL 24 HR SPRAY 60D  9300673831972
FLIXONASE NASAL 24 HR SPRAY 120D 9300673832146
```

***Note:*** Rows 1, 3 & 4 have duplicate product_names. This is what I'm trying to eliminate.

**Result I'm wanting**

```
product_name                      sku
FLIXONASE NASAL 24 HR SPRAY 60D   9300673808851
FLIXONASE NASAL 24 HR SPRAY 80D   9400600822438
FLIXONASE NASAL 24 HR SPRAY 100D  930067308851
FLIXONASE NASAL 24 HR SPRAY 120D  9300673831972
FLIXONASE NASAL 24 HR SPRAY 140D  9300673832146
```

Answer (score 0):

`DISTINCT` doesn't apply to a single column, it refers to the whole row. If you want to get a single row for a particular column, use `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT product_name, sku
FROM products
WHERE MATCH(product_name)
    AGAINST('Flixonase 24hr Allergy Relief Nasal Spray 60 Doses' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
GROUP BY product_name
ORDER BY MATCH(product_name)
    AGAINST('Flixonase 24hr Allergy Relief Nasal Spray 60 Doses' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Hmm, adding the `GROUP BY product_name` now no longer gives me the five best matches, rather five results sorted by `product_name` in ascending order?

Comment: You don't have `ORDER BY` in the query, why do you expect the result to be in any particular order?

Comment: I've added `ORDER BY` to order them by how good the match is.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. Now it solve with `GROUP BY` . 
My code:

`SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE MATCH(description)
AGAINST('my product description' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
GROUP BY product_name
LIMIT 10`

thanks @Barmar